# Regex for searching for a string followed by 11 numbers

Tags: regex, string, search, automation

I am using WinAutomation to search through an OCR extracted text file and to find the strings (there are many) 
tr00000000000

It always starts with tr and followed by 11 numbers. What would be the regex for this?

Trying TR.{11} and TR.[0-9]{11} and not working.

Comment: Try `tr[0-9]{11}`

Comment: Jesus it's case sensitive I am an idiot. Thank you, worked!

Comment: To make search insensitive, you can use so called in-line regex options. In your case it will be `(?i)tr\d{11}`, where `(?i)` tells Regex to use insensitive case search. Alternatively, you can use RegexOptions when constructing Regex, but in-line options allow you to change options on the fly. For instance, `(?i)TR(?-i)TR`. The first `TR` will match either `tr` or `TR` while second `TR` will match only upper case `TR` (`-i` means *disable insensitive match*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It always starts with tr and followed by 11 numbers.

You may use

```
tr[0-9]{11}
```

Here,

- `tr` - matches a literal substring `tr`
- `[0-9]{11}` - 11 digits.

Note that `TR.{11}` matches a `TR` substring and then any 11 chars other than line break chars and `TR.[0-9]{11}` matches `TR`, then any 1 char other than line break chars and then 11 digits. So, not exactly what you need.